# "Error in file(con, "r") calling maxent function in R

Tags: r, modeling, maxent

hope someone can help me here. I am a ecologist and as part of my master degree's thesis I am making some species distribution using the maxent (https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~schapire/maxent/) function in R, with the Dismo package.

In a certain point of the script (exactilly the one with refers to the model itself) I am using the follow command line:

```
me<-maxent(predictors,spp.occ,args=c("-J","-P","replicates=10","replicatetype=crossvalidate"),path='Results')
```

And I get the following error message:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'Results/species_9.lambdas': No such file or directory
```

After redoing the command several times exploring all its arguments I came to the conclusion that the argument that generates the error is the *replicates = 10*, which means that I want to replicate 10 times the template. I have perfomed with a smaller number of replications and up to 9 there was no error.

In advance I apologize for my language, in fact I am not a programmer, but I really need to resolve this issue and hope someone can help me.

Thank you very much.

The best,

Ramiro.

Comment: Looks like your operating system, whatever it might be, did not think that `path='Results'` was an appropriate path. You probably need to give a full path which generally would appear having an initial "/" and then other directory and sub-directory names, separated by "/", and perhaps a trailing "/". Read the `?maxent` page carefully.  The "replicates=10" does look odd but it does conform to the template in the examples. Appears it is passed to an external program named `MaxEnt` that is given responsibility for parsing it.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1):

Hey just looping back to this because the comment above did not fix this issue for me: When the `dismo::maxent` function breaks, it will often throw this error instead of actually telling you what's wrong. Navigate to the `path` folder and find the "MaxEnt.log" file. Open that with notepad and *that* is the actual error message you're looking for.

The error message here is a bit inane as the ".lambdas" file is a temp file that the function is supposed to create itself. It can't find it because it never makes it because it has quietly broken in a previous step

Comment: The `path` with the log file is the path shown in the console error.